# Maintain ViewState of Checkbox checked on paging in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, webforms

I have a `Gridview` with some data. In that I have 5 rows of `paging`. Whenever I check on `checkbox` in first page and go to second page and again I come to first page. The `checkbox` check value gets disappear.

The value of checked is not retained. How to get it maintain the `viewstate` of checkbox. Please suggest

CODE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDisplayCMMData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="heavyTable table" EmptyDataText="No records to display"
            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="grdDisplayCMMData_PageIndexChanging">
            <Columns>                    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SAP ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSAP_ID_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SAP_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID OD CHANGE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID_OD_COUNTCHANGE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID OD CHANGE DATE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID_OD_CHANGEDDATE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RRH COUNT CHANGE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRRH_COUNTCHANGE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RRH_COUNTCHANGE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RRH COUNT CHANGE DATE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRRH_CHANGEDDATE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RRH_CHANGEDDATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TENANCY COUNT CHANGE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTENANCY_COUNTCHANGE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TENANCY COUNT CHANGE DATE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTENANCY_CHANGEDDATE_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSTATUS_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("STATUS") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CREATED BY" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCREATEDBY_CMM" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CREATED_BY") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Reject">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprRejCMM" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>                
        </asp:GridView>
```

SERVER CODE

```
protected void grdDisplayCMMData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindCMMData();
            grdDisplayCMMData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            grdDisplayCMMData.DataBind();               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPCOLO_LOG"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Let me know if anything else is required

Comment: so is this webforms?

Comment: @JohnB: yes it is webforms

Comment: @JohnB: how to maintain the check state whenever a page index is changed ?

Comment: the checkboxes appear to be runat="server"` but you are not setting the check value

Comment: @JohnB: yes they are runat="server". also, how to set the check value and retain while pagechanging ?

Comment: the gridview control does that for use in its viewstate as it is also run at server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184741/discussion-between-bnn-and-johnb).

Comment: you are literally not setting the checkbox value anywhere

Comment: yes, i dont know how to maintain it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provided example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Maintance-the-CheckBox-7b9e9e1e).

check list is stored in view state as List.

Comment: i need to make it for checkbox on paging. i dont think so it will work

Answer (score 0):

To transfer data between pages you cannot use viewstate.

The options of transferring data **between** pages are Session storage, transferring via query string or storing the needed value into some kind of database.

Example for sessions storage at the most basic level:

*On first page:*

```
Session["CheckboxValue"] = chkSomeCheckbox.Checked;
```

*On the second page:*

```
bool isCheckboxChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["CheckboxValue"])
```

Comment: I dont have multiple page, its on the same page